# What is the time-frame for The Force Awakens?

Tags: star-wars, the-force-awakens

After watching Episode VII, I was talking to my wife:
"Wow, that whole movie took place in an afternoon."

My wife looked incredulous and replied "What? Are you kidding? It took place over a couple of months."

Now it was my turn to sit there in disbelief. "Then why was Rey wearing her ratty desert rags the whole time, even on the ice planet?" I quipped.

My wife insisted that she wasn't, but I think that's probably because Rey was wearing Finn's jacket so it looked to my wife like a new outfit.

Anyway, I have no way to back up my argument and could very well even be wrong!

How much time passed in-universe during the seventh Star Wars movie?

---

Comment: Dupe of [Over what period of time do the events in “The Force Awakens” take place?](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/111726/5184)

Comment: Darn it, my prose is wasted.

Comment: In the future everyone owns only a single set of clothes. /s

Comment: I answered the other one so we can hopefully close this one as a dupe soon :)

Comment: +1 for a better story, even though it is a dupe of the older one :-)